# How do I choose which font Chrome uses for cursive and fantasy?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, display-settings

How can I tell Chrome which font it should display when a website has `cursive` or `fantasy` for a font family?

Firefox has *abouf:config* settings for it.

[image]

Other browsers, like SeaMonkey and older Opera incarnations, even have neat user interfaces that let you choose from the list of installed fonts.

[image]

[image]

But not Chrome, it only has settings for `serif`, `sans-serif` and `monospace`.

So, is there a trick to use in Chrome? Is there an add-on that can let you choose?

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding Advanced Font Settings for Chrome.

Plus this code is for something like your profile text:
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

And this is for CSS:
font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;

To know how to use these go to: https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Cedarville+Cursive